# C++ makefile issue with removing unused libs

Tags: c++, makefile

Here is the makefile I'm using:

```
CFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags opencv`
LIBS = `pkg-config --libs opencv`

% : %.cpp
        g++ -lX11 -lcurl $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o $@ $<
```

Now I don't need opencv anymore, removing opencv from the makefile isnt creating any issues, however if I remove the included opencv libs

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

as well, I am getting the following compiler error:

```
KneckPrint.cpp: In function ‘std::__cxx11::string ProcessData(std::__cxx11::string)’:
KneckPrint.cpp:33:50: error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)’ temp.erase(remove(temp.begin(), temp.end(), '\\'), temp.end()); 
make: *** [makefile:5: KneckPrint] Error 1
```

The weird thing is it compiles just fine without opencv in the makefile but the libraries included.

Comment: What "compiler issue" does it throw? Please provide a [mcve], with at least the specific errors you're seeing.

Comment: KneckPrint.cpp: In function ‘std::__cxx11::string ProcessData(std::__cxx11::string)’:
KneckPrint.cpp:33:50: error: cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)’
  temp.erase(remove(temp.begin(), temp.end(), '\\'), temp.end());
                                                  ^
make: *** [makefile:5: KneckPrint] Error 1   ---   I hope this is readable

Comment: That error has nothing to do with opencv or makefiles, you're just passing the wrong arguments to a function.

Comment: But if i compile it with the opencv libraries included it compiles just fine and runs as expected, without it throws me the error.

Comment: I suspect that some `CFLAGS` that come from `pkg-config --cflags opencv` somehow modify the compiler's behavior (C++ dialect options?  stdlib include path?  could be many things).  Compare the `g++` command lines with and without opencv and I'm pretty sure you'll find the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `#include <algorithm>`, which will have been included by the opencv headers.

The error is saying that the only overload of `remove()` currently defined is the C one to remove a file, and that doesn't match the arguments. The iterator-based one that you are looking for is in the `<algorithm>` header.

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me crazy